# Object ID being displayed instead of JSON output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am outputting a JSON array of ActiveRecord objects, on my local machine running Ruby 1.9.3-p545 and Rails 4.0.3 it outputs the JSON perfectly using the .json extension, and also outputs xml if you choose the .xml extension.

The problem occurs when I deploy this code onto our elastic beanstalk environment which is running Ruby 1.9.3 with Rails 4.0.3.

The problem also occurs when I deploy this code onto our elastic beanstalk environment running Ruby 2.0.0 with Rails 4.0.3 on either Passenger (standalone), or Puma.

The output is only this when using the .json:

```
"#<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_CrmOrganisation:0x000000083ad5b0>"
```

The really weird thing is that this works perfectly when using .xml on both of the production environments, and also works perfectly locally.

I know it is nothing to do with the included relations specifically, because it yields the same result when the :include is removed.

Here is my code:

```
class ApiCrmOrganisationsController < ApplicationController

  include ApiHelper, ApplicationHelper
  before_filter :authenticate_company
  respond_to :xml, :json

  def index
    @crm_organisations = CrmOrganisation.where('updated_at > ? ', params[:delta]).order('organisation_name ASC').paginate(:page => params[:page]).per_page(params[:quantity].to_i)
    respond_with @crm_organisations, :include => determine_include
  end

end
```

Comment: did you define your json files in you views?

Comment: There's no need to do that, and it wouldn't work locally if that was the issue.  I've actually solved it, just about to answer the question with the answer :)  and it's a doozy...  4 hours of my life I want back ruby!

Answer (score 0):

This is now solved, and I'm answering to help future people who come across this problem.

The issue is with the following flag in the production.rb file

Default setting for production.rb:

```
config.eager_load = true
```

Change to:

```
config.eager_load = false
```

And it will work perfectly.

The reason there is a discrepancy between Development and Production modes, is that the Development default setting is:

```
config.eager_load = false
```